# Gnome shell in ubuntu 17.10 using alot of CPU

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

Since the update to 17.10 gnome shell is included in ubuntu what i love.
Before the update i always ran a gnome shell on top of it.

But on the gnome shell of 17.10 i noticed that the gnome shell uses alot of CPU. Not always but in spikes.

[image: See image]

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Are you in Wayland? If so, what happens if you switch to Xorg?

Comment: @pomsky if wayland is the default launcher of ubuntu in 17.10 yes i am. and i havn't tested that yet

Comment: @pomsky Still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely it's an GNOME Shell extension that you've installed.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable any new/recent extensions that you may have installed, and then log out, and then log back in. See if the problem is gone. If it is, go back and re-enable one extension at a time to narrow down which one caused your problem.

Comment: Disabled them all and seems to work. Should have tought about this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this as well, the CPU would never go less than 20% and would often shoot over 50% while just moving the mouse, and also the mouse cursor wasn't moving smoothly.

I was using Wayland and I just gave X11 a try and I noticed that it works fine on X.