# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome-Shell Extension CPU Usage

Tags: gnome, cpu, gnome-shell-extension

I am a big fan of gnome-shell extensions, except for the problem of tracking high CPU usage.

I run a lot of background scripts related to server management, therefore constantly constantly [logging in / out in order to locate which shell extension(s) has suddenly started consuming massive amounts of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008774/gnome-shell-in-ubuntu-17-10-using-alot-of-cpu) is, inconvenient.

My Problem:
gnome-shell is consuming ~100% regularly.. I can use cpulimit to temporarily put a leash on it, but av playback gets choppy.

Does any know a more efficient method of locating the problematic extension?

thanks

Comment: Maybe a simpler method exist, but `for i in $(pgrep -f "gnome-shell"); do echo "Tracing process: $i"; sudo timeout 10 strace -c -p "$i"; done` should give you and idea(*within 10 seconds windoe*) of what the running gnome-shell process/s exactly doing ... You can even attache to and debug running processes using other methods e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/1419821/968501

Comment: @Raffa  thanks for that.. maybe one day I will comprehend the output.. :-)

Comment: Alright :-) ... Answer added with another straight forward method ... I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test the behavior of newly enabled gnome extensions and how they might affect your CPU usage **without needing to log out**, you can run a new gnome-shell nested(*in a window*) like so:

```
dbus-run-session gnome-shell --nested
```

You can set the window size with the environment variable `MUTTER_DEBUG_DUMMY_MODE_SPECS` like so(*e.g. window size 1636x800*):

```
MUTTER_DEBUG_DUMMY_MODE_SPECS=1636x800
```

and use it like so:

```
MUTTER_DEBUG_DUMMY_MODE_SPECS=1636x800 dbus-run-session gnome-shell --nested
```

Extra information available at [`man gnome-shell`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/gnome-shell.1.html) and [`man dbus-run-session`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dbus-run-session.1.html)

The output from that session will also be printed in the parent terminal window for tracing/debugging.

**On the other hand**(*a bit more advanced though*), you can use [`strace`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/strace.1.html) to trace what system calls/signals are being used by/for the running `gnome-shell` process/s and e.g. print a *10 second* summary like so:

```bash
for i in $(pgrep -f "gnome-shell")
do
    echo "Tracing process: $i"
    sudo timeout 10 strace -c -p "$i" # administrator privileged account needed for strace to attache to running services
done
```

You can also attach to and debug running processes using other methods ... Some of which are discussed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419821/968501).

Comment: thanks for that.. the greedy culprit was the user themes extension

Comment: @nightwatch You’re most welcome … Confine the culprit :-)