# syslog very large, full of "Object St.DrawingArea has been already disposed error

Tags: files, error-handling, syslog, gobject

I found my root partition quickly (lets say daily, even hourly) full. took a look at the syslog and it was 18GB in size. took a look inside and it was full of two errors, one related to a specific Gnome extension (boom! disabled that, and wrote a comment on its github page) and the second:

`Object St.DrawingArea (0x55f7cc178c40), has been already disposed — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.`

of which I have no idea.

Ubuntu 21.10, Gnome 43, with the latest updates possible.

Comment: Seems, yet, like another gnome shell extension … I would advise disabling all extensions and debugging … please see this related post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1423509